# Migrated Iphone Build not connecting to Remote Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

Migrated worklight 6.1 project to Mobile First 7.1

Using IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160801-2314

Build app to work remote Mobile First server by giving correct Server path and Context path.

For local server both Android and Iphone builds are working fine but when I build for remote server, only Android build is working. In Iphone build WL.Client.connect is failing with giving error code 403 and for some times 200

Observed below thing by making worklightSettings include="true"
All remote server entries are reflected correctly on worklight.plist file but if I see in device(app -> settings) entries in Customize URL is reflected with local server details.

Also got to know from deployment team saying while deploying app on remote server app deployed successfully with warning "recommend to use extended app security".

Not able to identify where the issue is. As because 6.1 Iphone build and 7.1 Android build also working fine. Please help me out.

Found appid, hostname, context path and all other entries are reflected correctly in device logs and rest of logs which showing failing in connection to remote server as below.

```
      Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[389] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D0756EDE-2E8E-448E-BED2-9D8B3BF8A7F3 (sandbox)
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G34: launchd + 116796 [9F6284CF-8A17-36CC-9DB5-85D510A21F14]: 0x3
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: load
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: swizzled_init
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_CONFIG] -[WLConfig init] in WLConfig.m:71 :: {
        "application id" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        "application version" = "4.0";
        authenticitySharedData = "${authenticitySharedData}";
        buildtime = 1477023755;
        environment = iphone;
        host = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        ignoredFileExtensions = "";
        platformVersion = "7.1.0.0";
        port = 443;
        protocol = https;
        testWebResourcesChecksum = false;
        wlAppFamily = "";
        wlMainFile = "index.html";
        wlSecureDirectUpdatePublicKey = "";
        wlServerContext = "/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/";
        wlShareCookies = "";
        wlShareUserCert = false;
        wlUid = "w8FBWQAy5yeln7H1qfahMQ==";
    }
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:194 :: Splash screen image is Default
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:206 :: Screen resolution of iPhone 5 is detected. Splash image name is: Default-568h
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:194 :: Splash screen image is Default
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:206 :: Screen resolution of iPhone 5 is detected. Splash image name is: Default-568h
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: Apache Cordova native platform version 3.7.0 is starting.
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: Unlimited access to network resources
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 12.045026ms
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][wlapp] 0.349998ms
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 13.078034ms
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [WARN] [WORKLIGHT] -[MFPMainViewController viewDidLoad] in MFPMainViewController.m:97 :: WARNING: AutoHideSplashScreen key in Cordova.plist is missing or set to NO! SplashScreen will display indefinitley unless you manually hide it. Set value to YES to autohide.
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <CompatibilityIOS50ViewController: 0x16dbde30>.
Oct 21 10:09:22 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: Resetting plugins due to page load.
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/FBB95080-9634-4419-8396-604492D04B41/RBL%20MoBank.app/www/default/index.html#menu
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [ERROR] [NONE] Tried to record an true without a starting timestamp
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [FATAL] [NONE] Uncaught Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cancelSafeDocumentLocation at (compiled_code):1
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: log1
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [WARN] [NONE] Initialization option 'connectOnStartup' is deprecated. Use WL.Client.connect() to connect to the IBM MobileFirst Platform Server.
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] ondeviceready event dispatched
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [WARN] [NONE] Initialization option 'analytics' is deprecated. Use WL.Analytics.enable/disable to set analytics data capture.
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init started
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] Read cookies: null
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] CookieMgr read cookies: {}
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '27.729980' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] before: initOptions.onSuccess
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH] +[WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key: com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.rbl.mobilebankingiphone
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] after: initOptions.onSuccess
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] added onPause and onResume event handlers
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init success
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['UserAuth'] took '19.201172' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: getCommandInstance
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: enabledRemoteNotificationTypes is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later.
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [/apps/services/api/RBL_iBank/iphone/init]
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager invokeInstanceRegistrationRequestWithCompletionHandler:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:548 :: Call instance registration endpoint
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager generateKeyPair:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:] in WLCertManager.m:225 :: generateKeyPair generating keypair --> Success
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:51 :: Request url is https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:244 :: Sending request (https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers: 
    {
        "Accept-Language" = en;
        "User-Agent" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/5.5 (iPhone; iOS 9.3.3; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
        "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
        "x-wl-app-version" = "4.0";
        "x-wl-device-id" = "BADA3995-3328-45AF-AC5E-68EC987954EB";
        "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0";
    }
    You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs.
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:254 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x16d78e60>{number = 1, name = main})
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '126.935059' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH] +[WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key: com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.rbl.mobilebankingiphone
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [/apps/services/api/RBL_iBank/iphone/query]
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 401
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : Request failed: unauthorized (401)
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:51 :: Request url is https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
Oct 21 10:09:24 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000
Oct 21 10:09:25 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
Oct 21 10:09:25 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:244 :: Sending request (https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers: 
    {
        "Accept-Language" = en;
        Authorization = "{\"wl_authenticityRealm\":\"jHr3qLi1s9qLWIz8BTJbmfHa1bd+oJSbiDy3wxmnFsE=\"}";
        "User-Agent" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/5.5 (iPhone; iOS 9.3.3; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
        "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
        "x-wl-app-version" = "4.0";
        "x-wl-device-id" = "BADA3995-3328-45AF-AC5E-68EC987954EB";
        "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0";
    }
    You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs.
Oct 21 10:09:25 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
Oct 21 10:09:25 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:254 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x16d78e60>{number = 1, name = main})
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 0
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : The network connection was lost.
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [ERROR] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:509 :: Status code='0' error='The network connection was lost.' response='(null)'
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:512 :: Response Header: (null)
    Response Data: (null)
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager failRegistratioWithResponse:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:866 :: Response does not contain a valid certificate and client Id. device registration failed
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '19.790039' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager invokeInstanceRegistrationRequestWithCompletionHandler:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:548 :: Call instance registration endpoint
Oct 21 10:09:34 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager generateKeyPair:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:] in WLCertManager.m:225 :: generateKeyPair generating keypair --> Success
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:51 :: Request url is https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:244 :: Sending request (https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers: 
    {
        "Accept-Language" = en;
        "User-Agent" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/5.5 (iPhone; iOS 9.3.3; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
        "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
        "x-wl-app-version" = "4.0";
        "x-wl-device-id" = "BADA3995-3328-45AF-AC5E-68EC987954EB";
        "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0";
    }
    You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs.
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:254 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x16d78e60>{number = 1, name = main})
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '182.981934' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 401
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : Request failed: unauthorized (401)
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:51 :: Request url is https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:85 :: returning UUID from the keychain
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:244 :: Sending request (https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers: 
    {
        "Accept-Language" = en;
        Authorization = "{\"wl_authenticityRealm\":\"rzZHV8nu8HEiUXKrhmAbpLniktbeFpfUTs3nb6Bjzro=\"}";
        "User-Agent" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/5.5 (iPhone; iOS 9.3.3; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
        "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
        "x-wl-app-version" = "4.0";
        "x-wl-device-id" = "BADA3995-3328-45AF-AC5E-68EC987954EB";
        "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0";
    }
    You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs.
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://mobankmf.rblbank.com:443/qa/authorization/v1/clients/instance
Oct 21 10:09:35 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:254 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x16d78e60>{number = 1, name = main})
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 0
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : The network connection was lost.
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [ERROR] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:509 :: Status code='0' error='The network connection was lost.' response='(null)'
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:512 :: Response Header: (null)
    Response Data: (null)
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager failRegistratioWithResponse:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:866 :: Response does not contain a valid certificate and client Id. device registration failed
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed.
Oct 21 10:09:45 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/08/01 23:35:44
Oct 21 10:09:47 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{},"status":200,"responseText":"Invalid response when registering application","invocationContext":null}
Oct 21 10:09:47 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [ERROR] [NONE] [/apps/services/api/RBL_iBank/iphone/init] failure. state: 200, response: undefined
Oct 21 10:09:47 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [ERROR] [NONE] [/apps/services/api/RBL_iBank/iphone/query] failure. state: 200, response: undefined
Oct 21 10:09:47 Rajendra-Prasads-iPhone XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[389] <Warning>: [DEBUG] [NONE] Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{},"status":200,"responseText":"Invalid response when registering application","invocationContext":null}
```

Comment: If you debug the application and check the XCode debug console, do you see the URL as pointing to the local server?

Comment: As I am using Distribution profile unable to see Xcode debug console. I ran app on simulator. In simulator app is able to connect to remote Mobile First server. Only on device its failing to connect remote Mobile First server. On device there is no internet connectivity issue as 6.1 app is running smoothly.

Comment: Build the app in Xcode and into a device. The Xcode console should show the logs. The logs are required for debugging this problem.

Comment: How are you building your application to work with the remote server? edit the question with step by step reproduction.

Comment: Idan followed correct procedure to build and deploy remote server. Please find for edited question for device logs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two questions with the same errors as you, perhaps the solutions provided there will be of help:

- [Cannot login to app on iOS actural Device MobileFirst Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427691/cannot-login-to-app-on-ios-actural-device-mobilefirst-project)
- [Unable to login to app on device or simulator after upgrade to iOS 9 and MobileFirst 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237715/unable-to-login-to-app-on-device-or-simulator-after-upgrade-to-ios-9-and-mobilef)

Additionally, have you made sure to configure your application server with TLS 1.2 support, as well as set the application plist with ATS support?

See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/09/mobilefirst-platform-support-for-ios-9/

Comment: Hope host value is not an issue, as its build for remote server and it will reflect always correctly. As I mentioned above all entries in worklight.plist reflected correctly and able to see same on device logs as well.

Comment: Removing the security section from application-descriptor.xml and rebuilding and redeploying the wlapp files is not feasible in our case as we expecting no compromising in security concerns

Comment: Please give me direct link to download patch. I will try if issue can be resolved in patch as mentioned in link shared by you.

Comment: You are already using a very up to date build. The issue may be with TLS 1.2. Otherwise you may need to open a PMR.